# A question about terminology of repeating functions

Tags: terminology

Imagine some experimental data is repeating  in $\left(0,T \right) , (\Delta t,\quad T+\Delta t) , \left( 2\Delta t,\quad T+2\Delta t \right), ... $. I can not say the data is periodic since $\Delta t<T$. How can I name the data? Shifted or what?